# How to limit broadband speed in my flat?

Tags: speed, broadband

I need help with limiting broadband speed in my flat. There are 13 people living in my flat and there's only 20GB of broadband data cap to use each month. I was wondering if there is anyway to limit the speed from a user like me? 20GB is very small amount to use for 13 people and usually it lasts about 3 days the most cos people keep downloading alot of youtube video and other videos.

I am not an admin of the modem or anything, i'm just one of the user in the flat but i'm really sick of using dial up everyday. I want to limit the speed to about 10 or 15kb/s so they nobody can download any video or watch youtube video, therefore it would probably last long for a 20GB data cab.

Please guys, is there anyway at all i can limit it?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Do you have access to any of the network equipment? If not the modem, then the gateway router? If you can't control/modify the networking hardware, there's not much you can do (unless you're admin on all of the machines that are connecting).

Comment: You've got 13 people living there and you can't spring for an unlimited (or at least a much higher cap) plan?  Seems to me like it'd ba a good investment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have control of the modem/router I think the only way you could accomplish this would be to arp poison the network hosts so they connect through you and then limit that traffic. You could use [Ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/) to poison and [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) to limit ettercap.

[image: ettercap]

[image: netlimiter]

Answer (score 3):

If you were the admin perhaps you could set up a proxy that all the users go through, and that could enforce a download quota. Since you aren't the admin though you aren't going to be able to get in front of their internet connection in order to limit it.

Since it must also annoy other users though can't you all agree to pay a little more and get an increased quota for your flat? 20GB across 13 people is pretty low. Windows Updates could use up almost 1GB per month some months.

Comment: Yes i know, but we're student, so don't have a lot of money though lolz. But i'll try the software the is suggested above. Thanks